# Why is in OSPF LSA sequence nuber in range 0x80000001 to 0x7FFFFFFF

Tags: routes, lsa, ospf

Why is in OSPF LSA sequence number in range 0x80000001 to 0x7FFFFFFF. 
I suppose that it is for some historical reasons but cannot google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSA sequence number is a signed 32-bit integer.

So 0x80000001 to 0x7fffffff basically covers the whole possible range except one number: 0x80000000, and this special number is reserved.

You can read [this page of RFC 2328](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328#page-115) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As a signed integer, the sequence number counts from -2 147 483 647 to 2 147 483 647.

If it would count from 0x00000001 to 0xffffffff, it would appear as a count from 1 to 2 147 483 647 and then from -2 147 483 648 to -1.